# How to safely move an SQLite3 database?

Tags: python, sqlite, copy

I have a sqlite3 database that I created from Python (2.7) on a local machine, and am trying to copy it to a remote location. I ran "sqlite3 posts.db .backup posts.db.bak" to create a copy (I can use the original and this new copy just fine). But when I move the copied file to the remote location, suddenly every command gives me: `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked.` How do I safely move a sqlite3 database so that I can use it after the move?

Comment: Do you have write permission to the SQLite file after you moved it? If I remember correctly, that error can also appear in case you don't have write permissions.

Comment: Yes I do... unfortunately that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Have you moved the database copy onto a networked filesystem? For anything other than pure archival purposes, that's a bad idea (locking is famously problematic on non-local FSes).

Comment: Ah, yes, I have ... I need to access this huge database remotely this summer and don't know any other way than to use the networked FS I have available to me.

Answer (score 0):

You did a `.backup` on the source system, but you don't mention doing a `.restore` on the target system. Please clarify.

You don't mention what versions of the `sqlite3` executable you have on the source and target systems.

You don't mention how you transferred the `.bak` file from the source to the target.

Was the source db being accessed by another process when you did the `.backup`?

How big is the file? Have you considered zip/copy/unzip instead of backup/copy/restore?